# Problema con etiqueta <a> que envuelve a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy haciendo una página con prestashop y al meter código HTML me sucede un problema que me está volviendo loco.

Resulta que prestashop por temas de seguridad no deja envolver etiquetas  con una etiqueta  por lo que al guardar te lo elimina automaticamente.

Este es el codigo que quiero, pongo un ejemplo:

```
<a href="#">
<div>Hola</div>
</a>
```

Y al guardar hace:

```
<a href="#"></a>
<div>Hola</div>
```

Por lo que la solución que he encontrado de momento es meter la URL a través de JavaScript con el siguiente codigo:

```
const prueba = document.querySelector('.prueba');
                prueba.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
                });
```

El problema de meterlo así es que al hacer clic con botón derecho para poder abrir la pestaña en otra ventana, no me da la opción. Tampoco se puede abrir con la "rueda" del ratón.

Entonces mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera de meter un enlace al div para que prestashop no lo borre? O alguna manera para que el codigo JavaScript te dé la opción de abrir la URL en otra pestaña?

Comment: Suponiendo que quieres el div dentro del a porque el div a asociado a unos estilos.
te diria que pusieses todos los estilos en el a y evistases poner el div.
si no es ese el objetivo de poner el div dentro del a, comenta cual es el objetivo y a ver si encontramos la manera.

Comment: Es lo que comentas, yo quiero que la etiqueta <a> envuelva al <div> para que todo el <div> sea un enlace. El problema es que prestashop "saca" los <div> que estan envueltos por una <a> por temas de seguridad. El <div> lo tengo que poner si o si.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más sencillo sería modificar la visualización del elemento `<a>` para que funcione como un `<div>`.

La principal diferencia es que, por defecto, el enlace tiene `display inline` mientras que los div tienen `display block`. Una vez modificas esto con CSS, tienes un enlace que se comporta como un div:

```css
a.div-like {
  display: block;
  
}
  
div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.common {
 background-color: lightblue;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label>Link con Div:</label>
<a href="#">
<div class="common">Hola</div>
</a>


<label>Link comportándose como Div:</label>
<a href="https:/es.stackoverflow.com" class="div-like common">Hola</a>
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu respuesta. Igual que le dije al compañero de arriba: yo quiero que la etiqueta <a> envuelva al <div> para que todo el <div> sea un enlace. El problema es que prestashop "saca" los <div> que estan envueltos por una <a> por temas de seguridad. El <div> lo tengo que poner si o si.

Comment: Claro, pero como no conozco prestashop acepto tu premisa de que eso no se puede hacer.
Por eso estamos proponiéndote que consigas el mismo resultado, sin meter el <a> dentro del <div>.

Comment: Me confundí y usé un IMG en lugar de un DIV en el ejemplo, he editado para solucionarlo. Mi solución es hacer que un <a> se comporte como un <div> en lugar de usar un <div>

Comment: He probado a hacer esto que comentas pero prestashop pasa de ello. No hace que se comporte como un div por desgracia.

Answer (score 0):

Con Js podrías rescribir el código html como te venga bien.
por ejemplo pones en html:

```html
<div id= "este_div_solo_marca_el_lugar" ></div>
```

y luego en el js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("este_div_solo_marca_el_lugar");
    // Crear el nuevo enlace
    var enlace = document.createElement("a");
    enlace.href = "#";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "hola";
    enlace.appendChild(div);

    // Insertar el nuevo enlace después del elemento
    elemento.parentNode.insertBefore(enlace, elemento.nextSibling);

    // Eliminar el elemento original
    elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien tu problema, es que solo necesitas cambiar de lugar el `div`, metiéndolo dentro del `a`. Y que dentro de lo que puedes hacer es agregar una clase al `div`

Entonces simplemente seleccionas el div, luego seleccionas el elemento anterior (el `a`) con `previousElementSibling` y lo metes dentro

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const div = document.querySelector(".prueba");
  const a = div.previousElementSibling;
  a.appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
<div class="prueba">Hola</div>
```

Comment: Este ha funcionado. Ha sido la mejor opción. Gracias.